How to calculate $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\sin^{2}k}{(1+a\cos k)\sqrt{1+b\cos k}}dk$ (elliptic integral)?
My goal is to calculate $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\sin^{2}k}{(1+a^2+2a\cos k)\sqrt{1+b^2+2b\cos k}}dk,$$
where $a\neq b$ and $b\neq 1$. But we may simplify it into $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\sin^{2}k}{(1+a\cos k)\sqrt{1+b\cos k}}dk$ which is very similar to the complete elliptic integral of the third kind.

By residue theorem
Although there is an irrational term, I try to use the trick $\int_{0}^{2\pi}R(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)d\theta=\int_{|z|=1}R(\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2},\frac{z-z^{-1}}{2i})\frac{dz}{iz}$. Then, the integral can be written as
$$\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{(z^2-1)^2}{(z+a)(z+a^{-1})}\frac{\sqrt{z}}{z^2\sqrt{(z+b)(z+b^{-1})}}dz
$$
Here $z=0$ is branch point of $\sqrt{z}$ and also the pole of order 2.
Then, we may construct a contour as following
We first estimate the integral over $C_R$,
$$\left|\oint_{C_R} \frac{(z^2-1)^2}{(z+a)(z+a^{-1})}\frac{\sqrt{z}}{z^2\sqrt{(z+b)(z+b^{-1})}}dz\right|\leq \max\left|\frac{(z^2-1)^2}{(z+a)(z+a^{-1})}\frac{\sqrt{z}}{z\sqrt{(z+b)(z+b^{-1})}}\right|\frac{|\int dz|}{|z|}$$
It seems that the max part is not zero which is different from the complex analysis textbook case.
Is there any strategy to calculate this integral?

By elliptic integral!!
We thank @GEdgar and Z.G. for helpful suggestions. Recall the complete elliptic integral of the third kind (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral), which is defined by
$$\Pi(n,k)=\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0\frac{d\theta}{(1-n\sin^2\theta)\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\theta}}$$, the integral $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\sin^{2}k}{(1+a^2+2a\cos k)\sqrt{1+b^2+2b\cos k}}dk$ may be rewritten as some elliptic integral. But I didn't figure out how to deal with the $\sin^2 k$ yet.

Why do you want to estimate the integral over $C_R$, if your objective is to calculate the integral over $C_1$ (i.e., the circle $|z|=1$)? And what is the textbook case?

@ Gonçalo, since there are poles and branch points in the contour $|z|=1$, so I construct such a contour then I may use the residue theorem. The textbook case is usually $\int_{C_R}f(z)dz\to 0$ when $R\to\infty$.

But why do you think that the integral over $C_R$, with $R\to\infty$, will help you to calculate the integral over $C_1$?

@ Gonçalo My strategy is  $\int_{contour}=\int_{C_R}+\int_{C_{b^{-1}}}+\int_{C_{a^-1}}+\cdots$, $\int_{C_1}$ is included in $\cdots$, the left hand side can be calculated by residue theorem, and I may need to calculate all terms in right hand side to get $\int_{C_1}$.

Maple evaluates this in terms of elliptic integrals.

A related nontrivial treatment https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1940552/elliptical-integral-finding-i-int-sqrt1-k2-sin2x-cos2x-dx

@ GEdgar Thank you for your suggestions! I use maple to do the integral and the result is a very long expression with many many elliptic integrals $E,\Pi, K$.

By half-angle formulas $\cos k=1-2\sin^2\tfrac k2$, $\sin k=2\sin\tfrac k2\cos\tfrac k2$, subtitution $\tfrac k2\to k$ and symmetry in $[0,\pi]$, the integral in the title becomes
$$I=A\int_0^{\tfrac\pi2}\frac{\sin^2k\cos^2k}{(1-\alpha\sin^2k)\sqrt{1-\beta^2\sin^2k}}dk$$
where $A=\frac{16}{(a+1)\sqrt{b+1}}$, $\alpha=\frac{2a}{a+1}$, $\beta=\sqrt{\frac{2b}{b+1}}$. With $\cos^2k=1-\sin^2k$, $I$ can be written as
$$I=\frac A\alpha\int_0^{\tfrac\pi2}\frac{F(k)}{(1-\alpha\sin^2k)\sqrt{1-\beta^2\sin^2k}}dk$$ where
$$F(k)=(1-\alpha)(\frac1\alpha-\sin^2k-\frac1\alpha)-(1-\alpha\sin^2k)(\frac1{\beta^2}-\sin^2k-\frac1{\beta^2}).$$
Hence,
$$I=\frac A\alpha\left[\left(\frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha}+\frac1{\beta^2}\right)K(\beta)+\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha}\Pi(\alpha,\beta)-\frac1{\beta^2}E(\beta)\right].$$

Translate the interval from $[0,2\pi]$ to $[-\pi,\pi]$ and exploit symmetry, substitute $k\to 2k$, and expand into partial fractions:
$$\begin{align*}
I (a,b) &= \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sin^2 k}{(1+a^2+2a\cos k)\sqrt{1+b^2+2b\cos k}} \, dk \\
&= \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\sin^2 k}{(1+a^2-2a\cos k)\sqrt{1+b^2-2b\cos k}} \, dk \\
&= \int_0^\pi \frac{2 \sin^2 k}{(1+a^2-2a\cos k)\sqrt{1+b^2-2b\cos k}} \, dk \\
&= \frac{\alpha^2\beta^2}{2ab} \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \frac{\sin^2k (1-\sin^2k)}{\left( 1+\alpha^2 \sin^2k\right) \sqrt{1+\beta^2 \sin^2k}} \, dk \\
&= \frac{\beta^2}{2ab} \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \left(\frac{1+\alpha^2}{\alpha^2} \left(1 - \frac1{1+\alpha^2 \sin^2k}\right) - \sin^2k \right) \, \frac{dk}{\sqrt{1+\beta^2 \sin^2k}}
\end{align*}$$
where $(\alpha,\beta)=\left(\dfrac{2\sqrt a}{1-a}, \dfrac{2\sqrt b}{\sqrt{1-b^2}}\right)$. Drawing out the ultimate elliptic integrals is straightforward.
The first two terms are immediate:
$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \frac{dk}{\sqrt{1+\beta^2\sin^2k}} &= K(i\beta) \\
\int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \frac{dk}{\left(1+\alpha^2\sin^2k\right) \sqrt{1+\beta^2\sin^2k}} &= \Pi(-\alpha^2, i\beta)
\end{align*}$$
The third needs a little nudging:
$$\int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \frac{\sin^2k}{\sqrt{1+\beta^2\sin^2k}} \, dk \\ = \frac1{\beta^2} \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \left(\sqrt{1+\beta^2\sin^2k} - \frac1{\sqrt{1+\beta^2\sin^2k}}\right) \, dk = \frac{E(i\beta) - K(i\beta)}{\beta^2}$$

Thank you, the solution is Amazing!! But there is a little typo, c should be $c^2$ in the last line.
